# Clip inside of GeoTiff using shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip, boundaries

I'm looking to distract the red figures from the background imagery in the attached image. Normally i would use the clipper command in QGIS, but this only works if i only want to have the red figures part of the background imagery.

Can someone tell me how to get the red figures cut out of the background?[image: QGIS screenshot]

The background image is a GeoTiff and the red figures are Shapefiles

Comment: Would it be OK to burn the red figures with your favorite burn color into the image like in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work?

Comment: Check this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123652/49538

Comment: No not really tho, it has to be "no data", because it would interfere with the object that is placed on the red figures in the future

Comment: @FranciscoRaga that solution only replaces the values, thats not what i am looking for unfortunately

Comment: You can burn with the no-data color.

Comment: the point is, that's not how raster data works. you cannot literally cut out pixels, you will need to work with altering their values, e.g. changeing them to 'no-data', to be able to blend them out (I guess that's what you want?). ...well, if it's features you intend on showing there without the blending, I guess you could add a white polygon of equal shape underneath, but that's rather crude in my eyes ,)